# Java Loop and If else statments not completing

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

Hey guys i have this code I am working on for a class and I can't figure out what I've screwed up. I'm sure its something simple, so if you could look at it I and help me with my mistake.

Background: This is supposed to check a word to make sure it contains a punctuation char, an Uppercase letter and a lowercase letter, and a number with in the first 8 digits.

When I step through it in netbeans the for loop will only go to the second if statement before returning to the top and iterating again. it won't enter the if statement concerning the `numFlag` or the `upperFlag` and `lowerFlag`

I have those if statements checking to see if the flags are true or not so that if I have already detected the corresponding char type it wont enter and continue on.

It does compile, and runs i have included the main method I'm using to test as well for convenience if you want to compile and test it

Any other suggestions are welcome as well. If I haven't provided enough info please let me know what you need.

Problematic Code:

```
    public final class Checker {

    private Checker() {}

    public static boolean checkLegality(String _pass) {
    boolean puncFlag = false;
    boolean numFlag = false;
    boolean upperFlag = false;
    boolean lowerFlag = false;

    char[] pass = _pass.toCharArray();

    if (pass.length < 8) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

        if (!puncFlag) {//enters check for puncuation only if it hasint detected any yet
            int ascii = (int) pass[i];//converts to ascii

            if (32 < ascii && ascii < 47) {
                puncFlag = true;
            }

        } else if (!numFlag) {//enters check for numbers only if it hasint detected any yet
            if (Character.isDigit(pass[i])) {
                numFlag = true;
            }

        } else if (!upperFlag || !lowerFlag) {//enters check for letters only if it hasint detected both upper and lower yet

            if (Character.isLetter(pass[i])) {

                if (Character.isUpperCase(pass[i])) {//checks if upper case
                    upperFlag = true;

                } else if (Character.isLowerCase(pass[i])) {
                    lowerFlag = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (puncFlag
            && numFlag
            && upperFlag) {

        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
        }

   }
```

Main Method I use to test

```
  public class PasswordCheckermMain {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //TO DO CODE HERE
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String pass;
    boolean flag = false;

   while (flag == false) {

        System.out.println("Enter password: ");
        pass = in.next();

        if(Checker.checkLegality(pass)){
            flag = true;
        }
        System.out.println("The password meets criteria: " + flag);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: What password are you giving it?

Comment: Honestly it hasint worked with anything I have given it

Comment: If you are not giving it punctuation, then it will never reach the numFlag, upperFlag or lowerFlag branches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't do the tests in the `else-if` because then all the checks won't be done unless the previous was done.
E.g.

```
    if (!puncFlag) {//enters check for puncuation only if it hasint detected any yet
        ...

    }
    if (!numFlag) {//enters check for numbers only if it hasint detected any yet
        ...
    }
    if (...)
```

Sidenote, you don't have to do

```
if (32 < ascii && ascii < 47) {
```

This will work

```
if (' ' < pass[i] && pass[i] < '/') {
```

Answer (score 2):

numFlag only gets true when you see a digit, otherwise it stays false. When it's false, you get inside the if statement and do nothing else. So if you pass a password with only letters, you will never set numFlag to true, and never check for letters.

I think you shouldn't read the flags at all. You should read each character and check if it's a punctuation sign (set the flag) a number(set the flag) or letters (set appropriate flags).

Answer (score 1):

Why do you even check if a flag is already set? Just "or together" the results. Also, if you shorten the `String` with `substring`, you can use a "foreach" loop. And you don't have to cast a char in order to compare its value with an int:

```
public static boolean checkLegality(String _pass) {
    boolean puncFlag = false;
    boolean numFlag = false;
    boolean upperFlag = false;
    boolean lowerFlag = false;

    if (_pass.length() < 8) {
        return false;
    }

    char[] pass = _pass.substring(0,8).toCharArray();
    for(char c : pass) {
        puncFlag = puncFlag || (32 < c && c < 47);
        upperFlag = upperFlag || (Character.isLetter(c) && Character.isUpperCase(c));
        lowerFlag = lowerFlag || (Character.isLetter(c) && Character.isLowerCase(c));
        numFlag = numFlag || Character.isDigit(c);
    }
    return puncFlag && upperFlag && lowerFlag && numFlag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, if your password is 8 characters long, it will crash because you check the first **9** characters.

Your loop should be :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    ...
```

because the last index of a 8 elements array is 7 (since the first index is 0).

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in other answers, you shouldn't use `else if` but separate `if` statements if you want to allow to have letters before punctuation or numbers and so on...

May I also suggest you to check this by using a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), which should do the same job in fewer lines.

Comment: What if the password is longer? All we know is it has to be *at least* 8 chars long. It really should be `for (int i = 0; i < pass.length; i++)`. Also, this doesn't solve OP's issue. The issue is in the `if` / `else if` logic

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 no, it should check the password *with in the first 8 digits.* (it can be longer though).

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 you are right but I thought by reading the question that only the first 8 characters had to be considered.

Comment: *"and a number with in the first 8 digits"*, my mistake. Missed that initially. The latter point stands, though.

Comment: there is a check if it is less than 8 it will immediately return false.

Comment: @R.Hull No. The last index of an array of 8 elements is 7. So if `pass.length == 8` your last element will be `pass[7]`. You can loop up to 7.

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 
i agree i  need to change the iterator to `for( ; i <8 ; )`

but if the length is less than 8 it wont enter the loop anyways because it will return false

Comment: @R.Hull Exactly. Sorry if I didn't understand your comment correctly and to who I was addressed.

Comment: @C.Champagne  
I originally started with regex, but was kinda short on time. My reason for using characters being is that I was not sure how to dictate punctuation (which is kind of opinion based anyways).

My origional thought was to trim the string to 8
then remove all characters that i was not testing for ( be it upper/lower/puncuation/or numbers) the check if length is greater than 1

how might you suggest that? or can you point me in a direction?

Answer (score 0):

Basically i done is to change else if(if (!numFlag) for just if, add the try{      }catch(excepction e){ } for any unlike output.  Also in the main class, i change   the Scanner in for inn and close inn properly.
**PasswordCheckermMain class**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PasswordCheckermMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //TO DO CODE HERE
        Scanner inn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String pass;
        boolean flag = false;

       while (flag == false) {

            System.out.println("Enter password: ");
            pass = inn.next();

            if(Checker.checkLegality(pass)){
                flag = true;
            }
            System.out.println("The password meets criteria: " + flag);

        }

       inn.close();

    }   


}
```

**Checker class**

```
public class Checker {
```

```
  private Checker() {}

    public static boolean checkLegality(String _pass) {
    boolean puncFlag = false;
    boolean numFlag = false;
    boolean upperFlag = false;
    boolean lowerFlag = false;
    int ascii =0;

    char[] pass = _pass.toCharArray();
```

//adding try{ }catch{} for better programing
       try{

`if (pass.length < 8) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {


      if (!puncFlag) {
          //if 1 enters check for puncuation only if it hasint detected any yet
            ascii = (int) pass[i];//converts to ascii

            if (32 < ascii && ascii < 47) {//if2


                puncFlag = true;


            }//end if2



        }//end if 1

  //Note change else if for if      

         if (!numFlag) {
             //enters check for numbers only if it hasint detected any yet
            if (Character.isDigit(pass[i])) {
                numFlag = true;

            }



        } else if (!upperFlag || !lowerFlag) {//enters check for letters only if it hasint detected both upper and lower yet

            if (Character.isLetter(pass[i])) {

                if (Character.isUpperCase(pass[i])) {//checks if upper case
                    upperFlag = true;

                } else if (Character.isLowerCase(pass[i])) {
                    lowerFlag = true;
                }
            }


        }

    }//end for

    if (puncFlag && numFlag  && upperFlag && lowerFlag ) {

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;
    }

   }catch(Exception e){ return false;  }

        }//end checklega`

**OUTPUT :**

    Enter password: 
12@Abxyz
The password meets criteria: false
Enter password: 
12.Abxyz
The password meets criteria: true